# Inkscape : Flipping object vertically

Tags: inkscape, reflection

I want to create a reflection of my my pie chart, so I duplicate it and then flip it vertically, but I don't know why I obtain this strange result : the object is not exactly the same.
Am I doing something wrong here ?

[image]

Comment: This may just be a rendering glitch. Try zooming out and then back in again. This often fixes such problems. If that doesn't fix it, if can you share the SVG on SVGshare.com  I can take a look at it.

Comment: Indeed, it comes and go when I zoom in and out, but I can get rid of it. I will make another file tomorrow and see if it persists. If so, I will share the svg as you suggest. Thanks for your help !

Comment: So, that means it is probably a rendering bug. So, basically you can just ignore it. There's probably nothing you really need to fix (or could fix).  Maybe it's something you might want to report as a potential bug to the Inskcape developers. However, when you output your file as PNG or SVG, it should render properly in a browser. I guess my next question is have you tried that?

Comment: It was indeed a glitch, I work on a similar file and did not encounter that issue ! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a bug ... hard to say without svg.
my guess could be that there is som strange clipping/masking on  this.
you could try to select all elements of the graph and group then and try  to flip it it could help